# How to keep Ant Design Dropdown component background color same even when clicked (React, CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

So I'm using the following Antd component:

https://ant.design/components/dropdown/

And it has some behavior that I am trying to override. I want a dropdown with a white background. And the background is white at first:

[Background at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iRyL.png)

However, when I click the dropdown and move my cursor off of it, the background turns transparent:

[Background after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41b9t.png)

I've tried many CSS tricks, but none of them keep the background the same after clicking, and I need that.